# How to make a login page with Angular and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework

I have tried many times to do it and I waste a lot of time and still I end up doing nothing.

I am making an mobile app with Angular and Ionic, and I am writing it on Visual Studio.

I got some initial code from Ionic and I have my login page as

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
        // Form data for the login modal
        $scope.loginData = {};

        // Create the login modal that we will use later
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(baseUrl + 'Content/templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });

        // Triggered in the login modal to close it
        $scope.closeLogin = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
        };

        // Open the login modal
        $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };

        // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
        $scope.doLogin = function() {
            console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

            // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
            // code if using a login system
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.closeLogin();
            }, 1000);
        };
    }
```

But this is a modal view. And I want to do the login page as a initial separate page. And I also need server side authorization.

Anytime I delete this modal my app does not run... I am still a beginner and I try to learn by doing.

Can you please write me some steps how to do it and what is the best way to do it for an application that I am planning to publish.
Tutorials, books are also welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think you've jumped in at the deep end. Instead start on using and getting to know ui-router , this is used as ionic's routing inside angular.

Once you figure that out you'll be able to create new pages in your mobile app.

Auth can be hitting the server with creds and validation the user - once validated you could save a cookie or sessionStorage : note there are a number of ways to do this: basic Auth to name but one.

hope that helps

Comment: I have read about routing but I guess I don't fully understand it. But tell me what is the best way to do authorization in the server side ??

Comment: There is no best way - it just depends on needs. There are common ways like basic auth which uses the url to send users info https-//username:password@wesites-com/api

Comment: Every call to the api needs to check the creds of the user, this could be in HEADER[] , or POST. What are you using on the server?

Comment: OK I have made an API and I will be using POST